# How to covert GDB(geodatabase) to CSV?

Tags: csv, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to convert gdb files to csv files. Could anyone please share code how to convert gdb to csv file?

Comment: Where are you trying to implement this? If you are working within ArcGIS Desktop, use the model builder tool to perform these actions. You can always export the model as a Python script and use it wherever you want to.

Comment: I am trying in Arcmap, I got this error,                                                                                                Runtime error 
T
    return gp.listFields(dataset, wild_card, field_type)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 346, in listFields
    self._gp.ListFields(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to ArcGis and Arcpy, I got the error then I post this question before three weeks ago, I tried a lot to get solution, finally I have solved my error myself, The funniest thing is that I got this error because of path, I suggest the people who got the same error, first look at your path given.